# INSERT in other table with Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm Tried input INSERT INTO with other table, but I've error log:

> Mensagem 40515, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 18
> Reference to database and/or server name in 'deletadosYY.dbo.deletadosCadastroTeste' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

I have any possibility in do this, because I use azure server and I need change informations between tables.

My SQL code:

```sql
INSERT INTO deletadosYY.dbo.deletadosCadastroTeste VALUES (19,'Michael', 'Street Los Angelos', 25, '1998-12-25')
```

Answer (score 2):

3+ part naming isn't supported in Azure SQL Databases; they are contained databases, meaning that the reference to the database isn't permitted.

Omit the database name and connect to the correct database in your connection string (or switch the database context if you're in SSMS/ADS/etc). Then your statement would simply be:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.deletadosCadastroTeste ({Your Column List goes here})
VALUES (19,'Michael', 'Street Los Angelos', 25, '1998-12-25');
```

Comment: So I don't can send informations between two tables in diferents databases, is it?

Comment: As I mentioned, @ysilva74 , Azure SQL Databases are contained databases, and thus you cannot do cross database queries. This is a documented feature of the product; if there is requirement of cross database queries for your environment, then Azure SQL Databases are the wrong solution for you (you more likely want a SQL Server Instance in Azure). The above `INSERT`, however, does not need cross database connectivity as you are `INSERT`ing literal values.