# can not insert data to Azure DB

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am new with Azure.

I have created the free profile and log in the **Azure Data studio** to create DB on azure.

I have created the DB and set all Cols.

When I try to insert data it throw an error.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO [Test2].[dbo].[Customer] (SSQ1,SSQ2,SSQ3,SSQ4,SSQ5,SSQ6,QTSQ1,QTSQ2,QTSQ3,QTSQ4,
DPQ1,DPQ2,DPQ3,DPQ4,DPQ5,DPQ6,DPQ7,DPQ8,DPQ9,DPQ10,user_message,Name,number,email,CustomerBusiness)
 VALUES ('test}','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test'
 ,'test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test'
 ,'test','test','3','test','test')
```

I tried to connect and insert data in app.js (node.js), there is no issue with connecting with DB, but when I insert the values throw same error

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT in other table with Azure SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659506/insert-in-other-table-with-azure-sql-server)

Comment: Remove `[Test2].` from the SQL and select that database in the drop down list rather than connecting to `master`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Azure SQL Database documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql#t-sql-syntax-not-supported-in-azure-sql-database), 3-Part names in Azure SQL Database may reference the tempdb database or the current database. However, other databases may not be referenced with 3 or 4 part names.